# Sharepoint 2013 App upgrade issue

Tags: 2013, upgrade, sharepoint-addin

I met an annoying problem when I try to upgrade my new version app 1.0.0.1 to my SharePoint 2013 server.

The detail steps I did,

1. Create a development site in sp 2013.
2. Create a sharepoint-host app project in visualstudio.
3. Using "deploy" to deploy the app to sp2013.
4. Now the version number is 1.0.0.0, and everything looks good.
5. I made some changes and set a new version number at AppManifest.xml 1.0.0.1.
6. using

   $spapp = Import-SPAppPackage -Path .\DevCore.AppCalendar.app -Site [http://sp-ss2013/sites/testapp] -Source ([microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spappsource]::ObjectModel)
   $instance = Get-SPAppInstance -AppInstanceId 4c472c85-2759-489f-8435-c6cc7b11eb91 -Site [http://sp-ss2013/sites/testapp]
   Update-SPAppInstance -Identity $instance -App $spapp
   to update the appinstance.
7. after the update process has been done, check the app detail, it is the new version number.
8. But all stuff in app look the same, the change doest work at all

I tried iisrest but it turns out the same result.

Really need help, otherwise I have to reinstall the app......

/Dong

Answer (score 1):

i figure it out my own. besides changing the version number of app, we need to add ReplaceContent="TRUE"/ at element.xml and change a bit of feature.xml as we did at sharepoint 2010

Comment: Did you have any details on the changes you made to the feature.xml as we are experiencing the same issue without any resolution so far?

Answer (score 0):

What is your app displaying?

It could be that the browser is caching the apps javascript causing it to not fetch the latest version of your scripts. Try Ctrl + F5 to force the browser to retrieve the latest scripts

Comment: Hi Robert, the app displays some calendar and buttons. To do a trail, I only change the text of buttons between two version. I have already tried clear cache and reload.

Comment: Maybee you should clarify your question with this information?